# SOLR: minimum token size to be be spellchecked/synonymized

Tags: solr, synonym, spelling, misspelling

I'm facing the following issue: during the search with "ΚΩΣ" term, it starts creating combinations as if user have misspelled the search word: [image]

What I can't undetstand is how to configure this logic (as you can see on the screen, it has combinations like "κωσ" which have only 1 common character with the original query).

I want to make max number of changes to the term allowed (like maxEdits param in spellchecking) to 1, so that it won't return unexpected results.

My problem is that when I send spellcheck param as "false" to SOLR, result doesn't change (which makes me think it's not related to searchComponent). On the other hand, there's this filter called SynonymGraphFilterFactory [image]

That doesn't have any configurations like maxEdits allowed (searched through SOLR documentation).

Any ideas on how can I shorten number of changes to the original term? Or maybe I'm missing something important

Comment: You can use the Analysis page under Solr's Admin to debug exactly where in the analysis chain the term changes. The synonym filters are also easy to debug - the only changes that happen because of them are the synonyms as specified in the synonym files you refer to. If the synonyms are given there, expansion will happen. If you don't want that to happen, remove the line that specifies the expansion. Since it seems you have a private filter as the last stage, it's also hard to say what that filter changes for anyone external to the code.

Comment: the synonyms txt file is almost empty itself. So I guess it's not about it. But thanks a lot for the hint, shall try to analyze with the help of analysis page in solr